# How to apply Generic type for a variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

For functions, or for return type we will use generic type <`T`>, it is not throwing any error, but when i was trying to define a variable with generic type, it is throwing error, i can't able to define, here is the code snippet.

```
export class SqHandlerTemplate {
    component: ComponentType<T>;
    config?: SqSnackBarConfig;
    url?: string;
}
```

For the component variable, i am trying to give <`T`>, it is throwing error as cannot find name T or is there any restriction that we need to use T only for functions or return type?, please clarify me and help me out in resolving the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an expert, but I think `any` is what you are looking for:  `component: ComponentType<any>;`

Comment: add the <T> in the class, like: `export class SqHandlerTemplate<T>`

Comment: Please accept the answer so that the issue is closed. See stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer, and stackoverflow.com/tour to discover how to use StackOverflow at its best potential.

Comment: @Stewart Thanks for the reply, actually i should not use any, it should be strongly typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the template argument in the class name. You forgot `<T>` after `SqHandlerTemplate`.

So your code should be:

```typescript
export class SqHandlerTemplate<T> {
    component: ComponentType<T>;
    config: SqSnackBarConfig;
    url: string;
}
```

You have more information [in the Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: Yes, I missed to add that to SqHandlerTemplate. Thanks for resolving the issue.